# Make prestashop 1.7 name and description on 2 lines

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

everyone!

I need to make the name and description in the product miniatures on 2 lines. So what I did was, I changed templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\product.tpl like so:

```
        {block name='product_name'}
          <h3 itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}" class="product_name">{$product.name|truncate:45:'...'}</a></h3>
          <div class="miniature-description" id="miniature-description">{$product.description_short|truncate:45:''|escape:'html':'UTF-8' nofilter}</div>
          {if $product.description_short == ' '}
          <div class="miniature-description-2">{$product.description|truncate:45:''|escape:'html':'UTF-8' nofilter}</div>

          {/if}
        {/block}
```

This works to some degree, but I want it to always show the first 2 lines no matter how long the description is.

If someone can tell me what I can do to make it work, I would be really grateful.

Comment: any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend you to use truncate for description. It can contain HTML data and it's a huge probability that you will truncate it in an inappropriate place and you will lose HTML tags. What about your goal, I think that it isn't possible at all if consider it like a reliable approach. Because you can have any description and you never know what it contains. But if you want it exceptionally for your site you can add some conditional mark to all descriptions and explode them by it. For example

```
{assign var="desc" value="your_conditional_mark_here"|explode:$product.description}
{$desc[0]}<!--Part before your mark-->
{$desc[1]}<!--Part after your mark-->
```

But remember that it still wouldn't be reliable approach

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Alexander! I will try your approach, but let me put it that way - I know I have breaks in the description, so I want to take the lines up until the second <br> tag. The "I don't know what is in the description" part is because I do not know how long the lines are.

Comment: So then you can explode by <br/> tag and get the desirable part. But don't forget that by default all description is wrapped into <p></p> tag so you may miss closing <p/> part